# Alphabet letters are not querying from the the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table with column BarcodeID ( 1 2 3 asd) numerical values are working and I am getting the right output but alphabet letters are not working.
It gives me error

> Unknown column 'asd' in 'where clause'

This is the code I am using for querying.

```
<?php

require '../db/connect.php';

$id= $_POST['id']; // your post variable
$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, Items, Price FROM stockdata WHERE    BarcodeID=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>"." "."</td>" ."<td>". $row["BarcodeID"]."</td>"."<td>" ."Product:  "."</td>" . "<td>".$row["Items"]."</td>" ."<td>" ." price: " ."</td>"."<td class='price'>". $row["Price"]."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
}
else
{
        echo "No results found";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, Items, Price FROM stockdata WHERE    BarcodeID=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);
```

to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, Items, Price FROM stockdata WHERE    BarcodeID='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id)."'";
```

The magic happens in adding `'` before and after your value: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id)`

**EDIT:**

The reason why it worked with `'` is because MySql cannot interpret a `string` value if you don't mark it as `string`. `'YOURVALUE'` isn't doing more than saying "HEY! I am a `string`, so interpret me as a `string`!".

The reason why giving an `integer` only worked is because MySql can interpret any `integer` without marking them as so.

So your error occurred because it tried to interpret the `string` value `"asd"` without knowing it was a `string`.

Pretty basic stuff.

I hope I explained it well enough (not my native language).

Comment: The magic worked. But I have no idea why. A little explanation will be useful.